# Python type hint Callable with one known positional type and then *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, mypy

I the below function `foo`, which has:

- One positional arg with a known type
- A variable number of positional and keyword args after that

```py
from typing import Callable

def foo(bar: str, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Some function with one positional arg and then *args and **kwargs."""

foo_: Callable[[str, ...], None] = foo  # error: Unexpected '...'
```

How can I type hint this?

Currently, `mypy==0.812` throws the error: `error: Unexpected '...'  [misc]`

Comment: As far as I know there's not a way to do this -- you have to just type it as `Callable[..., None]`.  I generally try to avoid `*args` and `*kwargs` completely due to the difficulty of using them in well-typed interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use Protocols for this. They're generally a bit more flexible than Callables. It would look something like this

```
from typing import Protocol

class BarFunc(Protocol):
    def __call__(fakeself, bar: str, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        # fakeself gets swallowed by the class method binding logic
        # so this will match functions that have bar and the free arguments.
        ...

def foo(bar: str, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
    """Some function with one positional arg and then *args and **kwargs."""

foo_: BarFunc = foo
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this right now like Samwise's comment says, but in Python 3.10 (under [PEP 612: Parameter Specification Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/)), you will be able to do this:

```
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, Concatenate

P = ParamSpec("P")

def receive_foo(foo: Callable[Concatenate[str, P], None]):
    pass
```

I'm not sure if you'll be able to declare a [`TypeAlias`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0613/) for it though (because `P` cannot be used in global scope), so you may have to specify the type inline with `P` each time.