# When type hinting python functions, why are `*args` and `**kwargs` trearted differently?

Tags: python, types, pyright

I'm learning my way around type hints in modern python, specifically how to express the type of functions and their parameters.

If I have a function `f` and I know nothing about it, I can write its type as `Callable` (or equivalently, `Callable[..., Any]`); if I know its return type, I can specify `Callable[..., ReturnType]`, and finally if I know everything about it, I can write `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type, \ldots], ReturnType]`.

What do I do if I only know some of the argument types, but still want to enforce that contract? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968245/17700013) answer on stackoverflow suggests that a useful approach is to create a `Protocol` with a suitable example of what the call should look like.

Doing that lets me specify a type like "A function that takes an integer as the first parameter, and then an arbitrary number of positional arguments, and returns an integer". And indeed, the following type checks:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol

class Distribution(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int, *args) -> int:
        ...

def f1(x: int, s: str) -> int:
    ...

def f2(x: int, a: float, b: float) -> int:
    ...

distribution: Distribution = f1
distribution: Distribution = f2
```

That's great!

But what if I want to express the type of a function that takes an integer as its first argument and then an arbitrary number of keyword arguments, and returns an integer? The obvious approach would be to change the protocol to

```
class Distribution(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int, **kwargs) -> int:
        ...
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work; the type checker complains that `**kwargs` has no corresponding parameter in either `f1` or `f2`. Now, I can just about convince myself that either result (error or not) is valid:

- Obivously the code can't work! The protocol specifies that the function should take an **arbitrary** number of keyword arguments, not some specific ones. Indeed, changing the signature of `f1` to `f1(x: int, s: str, **_)` makes everything type check. In this view, `Callable[[a, arg1], a]` is not a valid subtype of `Callable[[a, **kwargs], a]`.
- Obviously the code should work! I specify that I want a specific argument, which is present, and then any further arguments are handled in the rest of the `*args` tuple. Both `f1` and `f2` match this spec, so there are no issues. In this view, `Callable[[a, arg1], a]` is a valid subtype of `Callable[[a, *args], a]`.

What I cannot understand, is why one example works and the other doesn't.

Does anyone know?

Edit: This appears to be a bug in pyright since the following also passes with no complaint

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol

class Distribution(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int, *args) -> int:
        ...

def no_parameters(x: int) -> int:
    ...

distribution: Distribution = no_parameters
```

Looking at their github it might have been [fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/commit/72d246fc4ff99dbc122b6b8288517e344c288b5c) five hours ago, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: _Is there any way of statically checking that the arguments supplied to the inner function are correct?_ Python is a dynamically typed language...

Comment: Sure, but tools exist to do static type checking - the information is just never passed to the runtime

Comment: what about using a different tool?

Comment: I'm confused - how exactly is `gaussian` expected to "know" that it is a type of `Distribution`? As you said, making it into a class sounds like the obvious solution here.

Comment: @jfaccioni `gaussian` isn't expected to know that. The `Distribution` type only exists to show by example what `_call__` should look like. This lets the type checkers know that `get_kernel` takes a function-like parameter, that should require an input array, some unknown parameters, and return an output array. `gaussian` matches this signature, so the type checker is happy.

Comment: I‘m not quite following your reasoning. The first code block does *not* typecheck on mypy-play. Also, the second bullet point does *not* seem consistent- your functions have additional *required* parameters, not „further optional arguments“. It is in fact impossible to use f1 in place of f2 and vice versa. So as far as I can tell, both examples don’t work and indeed both *should* not work. (This should also apply to your initial examples.)

Comment: [Your first example doesn't type-check when I try it.](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=d3c307cc14d0de92c0097f179fbc0350)

Comment: If that first example did type-check, the inconsistency would be confusing, but it doesn't type-check. Your `Distribution` says `__call__` should accept arbitrary positional arguments after `x`, and neither `f1` nor `f2` accepts arbitrary positional arguments.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oh, that's interesting: pyright doesn't complain about it, but I've just checked and you're right that mypy does. Hmm